# DELPHI XE2 DLL can't be added to C# application

Tags: c#, delphi, dll

For testing I am trying to call a Delphi XE2 DLL (see code) in a C# application (developed in Visual C# 2010 Express).

```
procedure CLP; stdcall; export;
begin
  showmessage('TEST');
end;

exports CLP;
```

However when trying to add the DLL as reference to a C# project the following message appears:

> A reference to 'D:\temp\test.dll' could not be added. Please make sure
>   that the file is accessible, and that is a valid assembly or COM
>   component.

When the same DLL is compiled under Delphi 2010 it works without any problem.

Any suggestions how to solve the problem are appreciated.

Comment: you've never accepted an answer here, or voted. I respectfully request that you read the [faq] and learn about these important parts of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot add an unmanaged DLL to a .NET project.

But you can import the functions, see for instance [Platform Invoke Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to link to an unmanaged, native DLL. You cannot add such a thing to a managed application as a reference.

The way to call your DLL is to use p/invoke:

```
[DllImport(@"test.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Stdcall)]
static extern void CLP();
```

Naturally things can get a bit more complicated when you start having parameters to your DLL but you can go a very long way with p/invoke.

One thing you need to watch out for is that your managed project targets x86 if your DLL is 32 bit, or x64 if your DLL is 64 bit.

As a final, minor, note the use of `export` is pointless in modern Delphi. You should simply remove it since the compiler ignores it anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. DLLImport did the job.

Comment: David, I'm sure you are right since you usually are :)  but please provide a reference to the statement about export being pointless. How does the compiler know which functions to make visible for import?

Comment: @VilleKrumlinde The `exports` clause determines which functions are exported

Comment: Thanks David, I misread you, I thought you meant the "exports" statement was pointless. I forgot about the "export" directive and I no longer use it either.

Answer (score 0):

Henk is right and I want to add a few things.

First of all, You can add a dll only if it is a .NET managed dll(which calls assembly). But you can import unmanged functions from unmanaged dll or exe files. So the right question is how I can import functions from unmanaged dll, and you should seek the answer for it. And I think the best start position is [pinvoke](http://pinvoke.net/) website.